# how to set jasper report band to don't occupied space when print when expression is false

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I want print section approximately half page size on bottom of every page only when boolean property (eg printFooter) is set to true. Assume I have in detail band 1 row element and printing thousands records.

I tried multiple ways to achive this as page footer, column footer ... bat problem is if i use "Print when expression" that band doesn't print but still occupied a space, another approach have footer on minimal size and use "stretch with owerflow" doesn't work either, as same as subreport and "Print when detail owerflows".

Now i have only two choices, one to create 2 reports and other to modify xml via java, but still i don't like this.

Maybe i miss something, so I'm asking if is there some solution?

Edit 150313-0723
Nobody have and Idea? Best solution yet for me is to create 1 "main" report as packaging an others 2 as optional parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution finally was to use 2 subreports. One of them have a pageFooter another one haven't. In main report i have in detail section code to add record ($F{_THIS}) to List parameter (another way is put to report data as parameter) and in summary band I have this subrepors with print expression, one if parameter is true another one if parameter is false (Subreport data is as: *new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{SubreportData})*)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Remove Line When Blank option.

Comment: I have it set. This options is good for band that is before detail and for detail bat after them its not do what I want. I think it will be probably problem of print order of bans. I think footer band release a occupied space bat detail don't expand